# NASM cmp error: invalid combination of opcode and operands

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am making a little asm x86 bootloder code to test cmp in asm, but it is giving me the following error:

`boot.asm:9: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands`

I am just comparing bx with 0x0107, they are all 16 bit numbers so I don't see any problem.

My code is the following:

```
mov ah, 0x0e            ; int 10/ ah = 0eh -> scrolling teletype BIOS routine

mov bp, 0x8000          ; Set the base of the stack a little above where BIOS
mov sp, bp              ; loads our boot sector - so it won't overwrite us. sp -> 0x8000, bp -> 0x8000

push 0x0107             ; Pushes 0x0107 onto the stack (Test number)

pop bx                  ; Gets the value and stores it in bx
cmp 0x0107, bx          ; Compares the value in bx to 0x0107
je  equal               ; If they are equal, jump to equal
jmp not_equal           ; If they aren't equal, jump to not_equal

equal:               
        mov al, 'E'     ;
        int 0x10        ; Prints a 'E' as for Equal
        jmp end         ; Skips not_equal

not_equal:
        mov al, 'N'     ;
        int 0x10        ; Prints a 'N' as for Not Equal

end:

jmp $           ; Jump forever.

; Padding and magic BIOS number.
times 510 -( $ - $$ ) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

Comment: You want `cmp bx, 0x0107`. There is no instruction for the reverse order. Consult an instruction set reference when you encounter such errors.

Comment: Also, your branching is over-complicated: `jne not_equal` will either jump or fall-through to your `equal:` block.  And you don't need to duplicate the `int 0x10`; both sides of the if/else do it so you could just sink it out of both, with `end: int 0x10`.  Then you're just branching to select a letter to print.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no encoding of the [`CMP` instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmp) that permits an immediate value (`imm8/16/32`) as the left operand.  You may have gotten a different impression if you had prior experience with AT&T assembler syntax, though (it reverses the order of the operands).